# Helios for Android / Timing Sunset pictures in general

Tags: sunset, android-app

So I recently tried to shoot some pictures of the sunset at a specific location, but once I was to late and another time I came about two hours before the sun was, what I thought, in the right position but then again was in the wrong position.

After a bit of googling I stumbled across Helios, but sadly it's only for iOS; So now my question: **Is there any good alternative for Helios on Android?** or **Is there any better way than using an app to time sunset pictures / pictures that involve the sun?**

Comment: Golden hour seems to be quite good, but it seems to miss the AR-Feature (with which you can see where the sun will be through you camera)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any app to show sun position and possibly also angle for particular times?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/75016/is-there-any-app-to-show-sun-position-and-possibly-also-angle-for-particular-tim)

Answer (score 1):

[Golden Hour](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplaapliko.goldenhour) is pretty good, but I also supplement with [LunaSolCal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vvse.lunasolcal) for geekier stats (twilight phases, azimuth and direction, etc).

Edit: [Sun Surveyor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ratana.sunsurveyor) offers AR (paid app).

Comment: As I already stated, Golden Hour seems pretty good, but it's missing the AR-feature which would make my life so much easier on a few shots I'm planing to do...

Comment: Hrm. Sun Surveyor might work. AR never actually occurred to me but I can see how it would be useful. I might have to pick it up myself.

Comment: Helios uses AR, that's why I asked for it. I mostly take nature/landscape shots, for which it would be extremely helpful to see the angle the sun comes from out of a very specific position

Comment: Have you tried Sun Surveyor for your self or just found it in playstore?

Comment: @Nanogamer7 I did try it but my phone doesn't have a compass, so AR doesn't work on it.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I now found a an app fitting my requirements myself: [Sun Position](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andymstone.sunposition)